# Assign multiple values in declaration part

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

I need to achieve the results by providing multiple declaration values. How can it be done?

```
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = 1   --instead I need to provide multiple values like @ID = 1,2,3

SELECT C.Name, C.EmployeeID 
FROM Cases c
WHERE C.EmployeeID = @ID
```

Table

```
Name   |    ID
-------+---------
A           1
B           2
C           3
D           4
E           5
F           6
```

And the results should be:

```
A           1
B           2
C           3
```

Comment: You can't. A scalar variable holds a single value. You need a table variable (or temp table or actual table) to store multiple values, using a join or IN clause for your query.

Comment: You should explain where the values come from & if there are always the same number of them.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life well over a year ago; you should really be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is with a table variable:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID INT);
INSERT INTO @IDs VALUES(1),(2),(3);

SELECT C.Name, C.EmployeeID 
FROM dbo.Cases AS c
WHERE C.EmployeeID IN(SELECT ID FROM @IDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is with the XML datatype.

```
DECLARE @ids xml = '<ids><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id></ids>';

SELECT 
    C.[Name],
    C.EmployeeID 
FROM Cases c 
WHERE C.EmployeeID IN (

    SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'int' ) FROM @ids.nodes ( '//ids/id' ) x( f )

);
```